# Fonts In WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

How can i embedded the font with project when i publish it. because when i publish the project the used font type doesn't appear.

```
FontFamily="GE Thameen"
```

How can i embedded the font with WPF project when i publish the project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx) for details of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it as a Resource.

Right click your project -> Properties.
Go to Resources and add Existing files.

Visual Studio will create a folder called 'Resources'. Remember to set the your fonts as Resources and not Compile!

Nice work, man!

Comment: Don't forget to set the FontFamily property according to MrShoes' link